# How to create a program to execute shell command in Windows?

Tags: file, batch-file, execute, livecode

I am trying to execute a shell command or batch file in LiveCode, however, for reasons unknown, it is not working. I would like to use another intermediate program to execute the batch file that records the output to a text file and then read that output with LiveCode as a workaround. What is a simple way to create an executable that can process a batch file?

There is not really any relevant code to share other than

```
put "test.bat" into tCommand

put shell (tCommand)  into fld "output"
```

Comment: Not understanding why you need an executable to run a batch file.

Comment: @Mecek this is definitely no duplicate of a C# question. Please, read the question. C# isn't mentioned.

Comment: @bbglazer If you want an answer, you need to include the relevant part of your script in your questions. Please, edit and add the code.

Comment: There is no relevant code for this question. I do not know the easiest way to build a small .EXE that can run the batch file I created. Then I will call that .EXE from livecode.

Comment: You already have an EXE that will run the batch file. It is `cmd.exe`. Have LiveCode run `cmd.exe /C thescript.bat`

Comment: @bbglazer the idea of SO is that you include code in your question. That's wht people down-vote your question.

Comment: @mark Yeah, I am finding this is a negative environment, like many other mass-communities on the internet. Oh well.

Comment: @Liturgist thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same result.

Comment: @bbglazer - Did you try `put "cmd.exe /C test.bat" into tCommand`? If this does not work, is there a requirement in LiveCode to specify command parameters separately?

Comment: @Liturgist, I did try, and I see no mention of specifying the command parameters separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following script works in LiveCode 6.7.6:

```
set the hideConsoleWindows to true
put shell("C:\test.bat")
```

My bat file contains

```
@echo off
echo 'test'
pause
```

and the value returned by shell() is

```
'test'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The last character of the value returned is a linefeed.

Perhaps you should try to reproduce this simple test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I put stuff like that, or common commands like "dir" or "ping", it works fine. For the particular program I am trying to run, it does not output anything if called from LiveCode. It does work if I call the batch file from the cmd terminal. That's why I am wondering if I can create an intermediate program (other than cmd.exe) to run the .bat file and return the output to LiveCode.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce exactly the same situation as described in my reply? Doesn't that work at all? Note that you need to reproduce exactly the same. Don't use a different batch file or a different shell command.

Comment: Yes, I did it as you just asked. The output in my message box is:

'test'
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: It means that it works. Now replace the syntax in test.bat with the syntax from your own batch file thescript.bat. Don't change the file names and the locations of the files. Does this work? If not, post the syntax of your batch file in your original question.